# Switching between statements if the user inputs something: infinitely and with a timeout

Tags: c, select, file-descriptor, timeval

To explain more clearly what I want to do, I want my code to check if the user inputs something (or if another file descriptor than 0 has data to read) every (let's say) 2.5 seconds and so until the program stops.

If the user inputs something, a simple `printf()` will notify him and then the program will check again if the user inputs something in the next 2,5 seconds.

Else, it should simply print that the time ran out and then check again for the user input in the next 2,5 seconds.

And here's the code snippet I stole from [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](http://www.beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/advanced.html#select) and modified to (try to) fulfill my requirements:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define STDIN 0  // file descriptor for standard input

int main(void){
    struct timeval tv;
    fd_set readfds;

    FD_ZERO(&readfds);
    FD_SET(STDIN, &readfds);

    tv.tv_sec = 2;
    tv.tv_usec = 500000;

    while(1){
        select(STDIN+1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, &tv);

        if (FD_ISSET(STDIN, &readfds)){
            printf("A key was pressed!\n");
            tv.tv_sec = 2;
            tv.tv_usec = 500000;

        }else{
            printf("Timed out.\n");
            tv.tv_sec = 2;
            tv.tv_usec = 500000;

        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

As long I don't press any key, this works fine and prints "Timed out." every 2,5 seconds. But if I enter something, it *seems* to ignore the user input and keeps printing "Timed out.".

On the other hand, if I declare the `fd_set` and the `struct timeval` **inside** the infinite loop, once I enter something, this prints infinitely that a key has been pressed *as if* it ignores the timeout.

I have no idea why such a simple code doesn't work. I guess I'm missing some point about file descriptors I don't know about.

Comment: Duplicate question — I'll track it down.  Basically, you have to set `readfds` on every iteration; `select()` zaps it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler what do you exactly mean by "setting `readfds` on every iteration"? Something like @iharob 's solution? I have already tried that but in that case the program prints "a key has been pressed" infinitely.

Comment: What iharob showed in his answer and what the duplicate question shows in its answers. After the call to `select`, the value in `readfds` has been modified by `select`, in general, so you need to re initialize it correctly on each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Because you should reset -> `FD_ZERO(&readfds)` your `readfds` and add the file desciptor -> `FD_SET(STDIN, &readfds)` every time `select` returns, since on timeout the file descriptor is removed from the set

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define STDIN 0  // file descriptor for standard input

int main(void){
    struct timeval tv;
    fd_set readfds;

    while (1) {
        int count; /* how many descriptors are contained in the set. */

        FD_ZERO(&readfds);
        FD_SET(STDIN, &readfds);

        tv.tv_sec = 2;
        tv.tv_usec = 500000;

        count = select(STDIN + 1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, &tv);
        if ((count > 0) && (FD_ISSET(STDIN, &readfds) != 0)) {
            printf("A key was pressed!\n");
        } else if (count == -1)
            /* check for the error here */
        } else {
            printf("Timed out.\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

as you see you should also check the return value from `select`, to check for an error, in case of an error, then check `errno` to see what happened, and then you check it the file descritor you're interested in is contained in `readfds`.

Comment: Are you sure this works? Anyway, thank you for the reminder about catching eventual errors.

Comment: I am absolutely sure it does. :)